# How can I use GL_QUADS in compatibility profile?

Tags: opengl, compatibility, primitive

My OpenGL version is 4.0. I want to render a simple rectangle by `glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4)`. 
Although I use **compatibility profile**, I still get `GL_INVALID_ENUM`. But when I add two points and use `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6)`, it works. So is there another way to use `GL_QUADS` or I can only use `GL_TRIANGLES`?

Comment: Why not just use `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4)` ?

Comment: "*Although I use compatibility profile*" Did you? Provide a full [mcve] that shows you created a compatibility context.

Comment: "Compatibility profile" means the `glad.h` is compatibility  profile not core profile.  Because core profile doesn't support `GL_QUADS` after 3.0,  I think compatibility profile support it.  And I use glad 3.3 compatibility profile.  But when I use `glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4)`,  there is an error `GL_INVALID_ENUM`.  I don't know why it occurs.

Comment: I forgot `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`,  I will try,  thank you.

Comment: @lucknitt the glad version you generate has _nothing_ to do with the context you actually create, and in the code of  [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61387287/2327517) you explicitly request a **core** profile.

Comment: I misunderstood **compatibility** profile earlier. I chang OpenGl profile to compatibility just now,  and it works.  Thank you very much.